# Angular/RxJS/Typescript thinks my data is an object and not an array?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I swear, RxJS is going to be the death of me. I'm pretty sure this is an actual bug with either RxJS, Typescript, or Angular's implementation of either. This works on [the RxJS docs page](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) (the javascript console on that page works as an RxJS sandbox):

```
  new Rx.Observable(observer => observer.next([{
    id: 0,
    name: 'John Doe'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jane Smith'
  }]))
  .map(data => data.filter(item => item.name === 'John Doe'))
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data), err => console.log(err))
```

But the exact same code is giving me the error `Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}'.` in my Angular application. Referencing the `data.filter` part. `data` at that point is most definitely an array, so I really can't figure out why it doesn't think so.

I have updated the version of rxjs that the application is using, but that didn't change anything. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. RxJS is already difficult enough without these inconsistencies!

Comment: That is a typings issue thrown by the typescript compiler. Can you post your angular code?

Comment: Hmm interesting `data` should be of type `any`. It seems to be caused by Rx. Not sure if it is by design. Anyway to fix it you could add type of your data wrapped in the observable, like `new Rx.Observable<any[]>`.

Comment: Hrmm.. any reproducibles? Looks fine on plnkr though. http://plnkr.co/edit/gKe19SNASo4trdpkjKl5?p=preview

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Thanks. Typing the Observable as <any> fixed the issue. Not ideal, but I've been working on this problem for 3 days and I just don't care anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `.filter` method inside the `.map`. Both methods iterate over your data, which means `data` contains an object when you are trying to access it inside the `.filter` method.

```
new Rx.Observable(observer => observer.next([
  {id:0, name:'John Doe'},
  {id:1, name:'Jane Smith'}
])).map(data => { 
  // data is an object since map iterates over your array
  return data.filter(item => item.name === 'John Doe')
).subscribe(data => console.log(data), err => console.log(err))
```

---

Update:

If you want to filter your data, you don't need the `map` fucnction.

Simply do this:

```
new Rx.Observable(observer => observer.next([
  {id:0, name:'John Doe'},
  {id:1, name:'Jane Smith'}
]))
.filter(item => item.name === 'John Doe')
.subscribe(data => console.log(data), err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Don't forget to return a value in the map function. I assume you want to `return data.filter(item => item.name === 'John Doe');`

Comment: I don't understand. The RxJS `.map` operator applies a mapping function to each value emitted from the observable. In this case the value emitted is the array. Not the objects inside the array.

Your code is the same as what I provided and causes the same error. How am I supposed to filter the array other than using a `.filter` inside a `.map`?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a solution which should work for you.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with your updated solution. The second `.filter` is throwing the error: `Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Comment: oops sry where was my mind. now it's correct. remove the second filter

Comment: That doesn't work either. Nothing passes the filter and gets emitted. `.filter` doesn't work that way. It's the RxJS operator `.filter` not a typical array `.filter`. In your updated solution it is taking the entire array as `item`, not the object inside the array.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter

Answer (score 1):

This is typescript side issue, not actual code side behavior. If you run this code as is on JS, you can see values are logged via subscription.

Main problem in here is, when you create observable via `new Observable()` ctor, it is not able to infer type of observable via subscribe function you provided but instead type inference flow from `Observable<T>` to subscribe function parameter. Cause of those, your observable's type becomes `Observable<{}>`, and it makes fails to access prototype of array.

Creating Observable via `new Observable<Array<{id: number, name: string}>>` makes observable operator correctly infer type of values. Or more better, static creation method will provide type inferences for value - like

```
Rx.Observable.of([{
  id: 0,
  name: 'John Doe'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Jane Smith'
}])
.map(data => data.filter(item => item.name === 'John Doe'))
.subscribe(data => console.log(data), err => console.log(err))
```